# Can I prevent my opponent from looking at cards with Vizier of the Menagerie while I'm Mindslaving them?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Vizier of the Menagerie](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=426894) says "You may look at the top card of your library," and [Mindslaver](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=209044) says you "make all decisions for the player."

What I'm wondering is can the player who's being controlled see the top card of their library as their turn is taken for them? In other words, if I'm Mindslavering someone and I get to make all decisions for them, then I get to decide when they look at the top card of their library, so I can decide that they don't get to look at it.

I'm not sure about this, but based on all the Gatherer rules, I would say that the controlled player and the controlling player can both look at the card because the card becomes part of the "known information" to the player who controls the Vizier (so they can always know it) and since they always know it, the Mindslaver controller also knows it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes, the Mindslaver's controller may prevent the controlled player from taking that specific action.**

---

Mindslaver's rulings say:

> **You get to make every decision the other player would have made** during that turn. You can’t make any illegal decisions or illegal choices — you can’t do anything that player couldn’t do. You can spend mana in the player’s mana pool only on that player’s spells and abilities. The mana in your mana pool can be spent only on your spells and abilities.

Since looking at the top card of your library is an action you **may** take while controlling Vizier of the Menagerie, the player controlling the turn may simply choose not to take this action.

Comment: I think you misread the question. It wasn't asking if the controlling player could look at the card... it was asking if the controlling player can prevent the controlled player from looking at the card.

Comment: @GendoIkari that's exactly what my answer says. The controlling player cannot prevent the controlled player from looking at the card because every action is still taken **by the controlled player**, although the controlling player is the one choosing which actions are those.

Comment: No, the question wasn't about the controller looking at the card without the controlled also seeing it. It was about if the controller can simply make the controlled choose to not do the "look at the top card" action; meaning neither player would see it.

Comment: This sounds likely correct to me, but I was hoping there was some comp rule that clarified that a "card you may look at" is not the same as a something that is known information to you.